# Flash poor performance with vector art (.svg)

Tags: actionscript, flash, vector-graphics

When using multiple pieces of vector art I've noticed that performance gets rather sloppy, so I created a simple test program that displays 100 copies of the same graphic and allows zooming. I used what I believe to be a fairly simple vector image (can see links below). However, fps drops massively when zooming in or out. I know zooming requires a lot of calculations, but I have an above average system (i5 2500k processor) that I would expect to handle such demands. Is there something I'm missing?

Picture of image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBxQO.png

SVG file - http://pastebin.com/MjBLebFQ

```
package 
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Main extends Sprite 
{
    [Embed(source = "../lib/Doctor.svg")]
    private var Doctor:Class;

    private var container:Sprite = new Sprite();

    public function Main():void 
    {
        container = new Sprite();
        for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (var j:int = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                var s:Sprite = new Doctor();
                s.x = i * 20;
                container.addChild(s);                  
            }
        }
        this.addChild(container);
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, onMouseWheel);
    }

    private function onMouseWheel(event:MouseEvent):void
    {                               
        if (event.delta > 0) {
            container.scaleX += 0.1;
            container.scaleY += 0.1;
        }else {
            container.scaleX -= 0.1;
            container.scaleY -= 0.1;
        }

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Vector rendering performance in Flash is quite poor - have you considered converting them to bitmaps or setting `cacheAsBitmap` to `true` on the sprites?

Comment: what Marty Wallace said.  additionally you could consider caching the image at each scale (so you only render it once for each scale).